# Image resizing:hover

Tags: html, css

I can't make this working right. When the user have mouse ouver this div, how can i make this without having the image resizing?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P9zaZ/)

HTML:

```
<div id="highlight" class="outerbox">   
    <div id="boxTitle">
        Highlight
    </div>
<img src="http://lookouch.com/www/assets/newImages/home/modulos/1.jpg"/>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#boxTitle { 
    color: #ffffff; 
    background-color: #6000ff; 
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px; 
    position: absolute; 
    font-family: Montserrat; 
    font-size: 13px; 
    display: inline-block; 
    top: 0; 
    left: 0; 
}

#highlight { width: 100%; display: inline-block; position: relative; }
#highlight img { width: 100%; height: 100%; }

#highlight:hover { 
    border: 2px solid #6000ff; 
    box-sizing: border-box; 
    overflow: hidden; 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Three things:

1. Give the highlight div a transparent border: `border: 2px solid transparent;`. This will stop the jumping.
2. Add `vertical-align:top;` to `#highlight img` to remove the gap under the image.
3. Remove `box-sizing: border-box;` from `#highlight:hover`. It's not needed here.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/P9zaZ/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Applying the border on hover reduces the inner size of the div, causing your `width: 100%; height: 100%` image to reduce as well.

Give the div a transparent border before it's hovered, so it will not have any inner size change:

```
#highlight {
    border: 2px solid transparent;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/P9zaZ/2/

Answer (score 0):

You could use `outline` instead of `border`: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P9zaZ/3/)

There's a downside though: `border-radius` doesn't affect `outline` like it does with `border`.